# Woocommerce sliding cart - add remove button for each product

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I use WooCommerce Cart Tab.
It is possible to add a remove button for a product?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As for me the solution of Daniel didn't work, the following code did the job:

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', 
sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="remove" title="%s">&times;</a>', 
esc_url( WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
 __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ) ), $cart_item_key );
```

Please note the `WC()->cart` instead of `$woocommerce->cart` Hope this can help others if the above solution is not working either :)